# How to programmatically access the host computer's ip address when debugging a React Native app on a real device

Tags: react-native

I am running a React Native app for debugging on my actual iPhone, and I need to get the IP address of my computer, as I have the API server running there as well. The [React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device?platform=ios#2-ip-address) indicate that the build scripts generate an `IP.txt` file that includes this IP address that I'm looking for. These docs also state it "gets embedded in the app," and I know it's used to get the `jsBundleURL` in [Native code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0fd7bd3a7f62b72f70da42608ff933a9fb1a63d9/packages/react-native/template/ios/HelloWorld/AppDelegate.mm#L25), but I'm curious how to access this in JavaScript code for use within my app's code.

I do not want to hardcode this, as I develop on multiple machines, so this should "just work" once I figure out the right way to grab the IP programmatically.